# Django - create CSV on the fly and save it to filesystem and model file field

Tags: python, django

In my django app, I have a management command which I want to use to process some data and create a model instance as well as file in filesystem and save its path to above instance's file field.

My management command:

```
import datetime
import timy
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import tempfile
from core.models import Entry
from np_web.models import Dump
import calendar
import csv

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Create dump and file for current day'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        with timy.Timer() as timer:
            today = datetime.date.today()
            dump_title = '{}.{}.{}.csv'.format(today.day, today.month, today.year)

            entries = Entry.objects.all()

            dump = Dump.objects.create(all_entries=entries.count())
            dump.save()

            print('Dump created with uuid:', dump.uuid)
            print('Now create data file for dump')
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_csv:
                writer = csv.writer(temp_csv)
                writer.writerow([
                    'Column1',
                    'Column2',
                   ])
                for entry in entries:
                    writer.writerow([
                        entry.first_name,
                        entry.last_name
                    ])
            dump.file.save(dump_title, temp_csv)
```

My Dump model:

```
class Dump(BaseModel):
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    all_entries = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name=_('Attachment'), upload_to=dump_file_upload_path, max_length=2048,
                            storage=attachment_upload_storage, null=True, blank=True)
```

Anyway, it doesn't work. It is throwing an error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I am also not sure if using temporary file is a best solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments to hopefully direct you to a solution.

For starters, ["If delete is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html), and assuming that the spacing you have is correct, you are closing the file prior to attempting to save the file. This would result in the file being empty.

My suggestion would be to simply create the file like normal, and delete it afterwards. A simple approach (though there may be a better) would be to create the file, save it, and then remove the original (temp) copy.

In addition, when saving the file, you want to save it using Django's File wrapper.

So you could do something like the following:

```
from django.core.files import File
import os

with open(temp, 'rb') as f:
    doc_file = File(f)
    dump.file.save("filename", doc_file, True)
    dump_file.save()

try:
    os.remove(temp)
except Expection:
    print('Unable to remove temp file')
```